# Extending the Google Calendar Event to include custom properties

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am trying to extend the Google Calendar Event card (for Creating, Viewing and Editing events) to show a custom property on the popup when a user views or edits an event.  I have created the WorkSpace Apps Script AddOn, got the manifest file working, OAuth and scripting done.  Triggers are working as expected, and I can display data in the Card on the right of the screen, but for the life of me I cannot find how to add a single sentence to the event popup, similar to the below screenshot.

I know it is possible as other have done, but cannot find the documentation or even what it is call.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?
[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea for this?